# Создание ошибок в javascript

Tags: javascript

Пишу я функцию сложения чисел (пример). Нужно во внутрь функции вставить проверку на то не является ли один из аргументов строкой. Если является выкинуть ошибку.

Вот тут как раз проблема. Каким образом идеологически это будет правильно сделать?

Просто выкинуть `false`? или создать `new Error()`. И если функция вернет ошибку есть ли метод для проверки, ошибка это или нет.

В общем хочется грамотно оформлять исключения и доносить это в каком-то виде до разработчика.

Comment: в яваскрипте присутствует `try{}catch(){}` который может поймать ошибку

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно делают так: `throw "Данный метод не может принимать строку в качестве аргумента"`.

Если ошибка некритична (программа может продолжить выполнение) - то можно сделать так: `console && console.error("Данный метод не может принимать строку в качестве аргумента")`. Первая часть конструкции нужна для IE, у которого консоль отсутствует пока пользователь не откроет ее.

Если предполагается, что функцию будут использовать по всему миру - сообщение об ошибке лучше писать на английском.

Делать какие-либо сложные классы для ошибок - не лучшая идея, ведь подобные ошибки должны исправляться программистом - а потому не предназначены для автоматической обработки.

Comment: всегда ли у `console` присутствует метод `.error()`? Где-то мне попадалась ситуация, что только `.log()`

Comment: @Sergiks [Firefox 4+, IE8+](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/error).

Comment: Не плохой вариант.

Answer (score 2):

```
function calc (a,d)
{
    // код
    if (проверка на строку) {
       throw new NotInt("переменная является строкой");
    }

    // код
}
```

NotInt - этот объект вы создаете сами нужную вам ошибку, чтобы перехватывать ее

```
function NotInt(message) {
   this.message = 'не число';
   this.name = "NotInt";
}
```

потом вызываешь функцию

```
try {
    // вызываете функцию в которой может быть ошибка
    calc (a,d);
} catch(e) {
    // тут мы перехватываем нужную нам ошибку
    if (e instanceof NotInt) {
         // какая то логика если получили такую ошибку
      }
}
```

Comment: С такими ошибками есть одна проблема - нет никакой логики, которую можно было бы написать в случае получения ошибки. В нормально работающей программе подобная ошибка попросту никогда не будет возникать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не совсем понял ваш комментарий :-) если так подходить: _В нормально работающей программе_ никакая ошибка произойти не может, потому что она нормально работает :)

Comment: @Grundy я имел в виду что программа дописана до конца, и все ее элементы правильно состыкованы друг с другом. В такой программе могут происходить ошибки валидации, сетевые ошибки, ошибки бизнес-логики...

Comment: я просто привел пример, так это можно использовать, на деле можно тупо перехватывать обычные эксепшины

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в принципе пример можно отнести к классу ошибок валидации

Comment: @Grundy нет, ошибка контракта ошибкой валидации не является. Потому что, во-первых, функция суммирования чисел не обладает знанием о происхождении этих чисел - а потому не может сформировать корректное сообщение с точки зрения задачи валидации. А во-вторых, настолько "глубоко" невалидные данные проникать в программу не должны ни в коем случае.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, случаи разные бывают :-) но на то это и пример чтобы поверхностно показать, можно было сделать: `function executeA()` и ошибку какую-нибудь `not valid condition` и вполне себе вариант для  кастомной ошибки

Answer (score 1):

```
function calc(arguments) {
    if(typeof arg = "string") {
        throw "Текст ошибки";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...

```
try{
  add(a, b);
} catch (e) {
    document.write('Text error');
  }
```

Делать нужно так. Только в catсh нужно конечно обрабатывать исключение и писать, что конкретно нужно сделать в случае его возникновения. Это так - для примера.